# My sculpting is not working

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, sculpt-mode

I don't know why but my sculpting does not work, I have tried other files and it works fine there.
I have tried other objects in the same file and it works just fine, but this bear just doesn't work.

I do have added a subdivide modifier, so maybe that's the problem but when I applied it, it still did not work and when I deleted it it still didn't work. It looks like I didn't click the bear because it is so gray.

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file (copy paste the URL it will create): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be, that you accidentally turned on the mask?

You could try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>M</kbd> to clear it and see if you than can sculpt again.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked!! i could have never have found that!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem, I'm happy it was an easy fix

Comment: @christiaan Hello and welcome. Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).